# Reference counting: how to make sure two linked objects keep existing when you own at least one?

Tags: memory-management, reference-counting

Let's say I have two objects: `A` and `B`.

Both objects have a reference count property.

`A` and `B` may be created independently. Their reference count is initialized to 1 on creation.

`A` may be associated to `B`. When this happens, `A` gets a reference to `B` (`B`'s reference count is incremented), and `B` gets a weak reference to `A` (to avoid cycles).

If `A` is associated to `B`, and you own a reference to *either* `A` or `B` (or both), `A` and `B` must *not* be destroyed. Both objects need to be destroyed when all external references to them are lost.

Here's the problematic situation with typical strong and weak references:

```
A = createA()   # A's ref count: 1
B = createB()   # B's ref count: 1
associate(A, B) # B's ref count: 2
put(A)          # A's ref count: 0
  -> A is destroyed
  -> B is put by A (B's ref count: 1)
  -> B is notified that A was destroyed
    -> B's weak reference to A is reset
```

`A` should not be destroyed here because you still own a reference to `B`.

How can this be achieved?

Let me also tell you that `createA()`, `createB()`, and `associate()` are part of an existing API which cannot be broken. The internal structure of `A` and `B` may be changed, however.

Answer (score 1):

The way that you've laid out this problem, it can't be solved.  That's why weak/strong schemes always have the concept of the "owner" or "parent" which is the one with the strong references and which must be the one that you keep alive the longest.

To have cyclic references between objects, no manual lifetime management, and lifetimes of the objects dependent upon the whole cycle, then you need a garbage collector.